# Fizzbuzz Example: What is the purpose of the equal-to operator in this example?

Tags: javascript

I know there are easier and quicker ways to write this program. However, I'm having trouble understanding why the equal-to operator is needed here? Referring to the `== 0` instances below.

```
for(let x=1;x<101;x++) {
    if(x % 3 == 0 && x % 5 == 0){
        console.log('fizzbuzz')
    } else if(x % 3 == 0) {
         console.log('fizz')
    } else if(x % 5 == 0) {
         console.log('buzz')
    } else {
        console.log(x)
    }
}
```

Comment: `x % 3 == 0` would be true when i x is a multiply of 3

Comment: So you can test for equality? It's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: One generally uses the equals operator when one wants to test for equality.  It's unclear what other answer you're expecting.

Comment: Google "how to check if a number is a multiple in javascript"

Comment: [Modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) might be causing your confusion?

Comment: Maybe your real confusion stems from misunderstanding what `%` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x % 3 == 0` is checking to see if `x` is evenly divisible by three. If it isn't, then there will be a non-zero remainder. (The `x % 3` part of that expression uses the `%` operator to get the remainder after division.)